# error Importing urllib and import http.client

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I write this Python code

```
import  urllib.request,json

def main():

    data=urllib.request.urlopen("http://selling.alruabye.net/UsersWS.asmx/GetToolType?lng=ar").read()
    jsonr=json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
    #print(jsonr,type(jsonr))
    for row in jsonr['ToolData']:
        print(row['ToolTypeName'])



if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

but when i want to run it i got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/PycharmProjects/learnpy/http.py", line 1, in <module>
    import  urllib.request,json
  File "C:\path\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'; 'http' is not a package
```

i tried to search for a soulotion or import the library like:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import json
```

but not working for me, My Python version is: 3.7.0
i use Pycharm

Comment: Your file is named `http.py`, which is likely interfering with the import of the built in package [`http`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html).  Try renaming your file.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Fixed thank you :)

Comment: Patrick, you should formulate an answer, definitely helped me!

Answer (score 2):

the problem is fixed by changing the file name from http.py as @[Patrick Haugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6779307/patrick-haugh)
suggest in the comments

thanks